# giving initial value raises 'value for field is required' error in django

Tags: django, forms, field

Django form trips me many times...

I gave initial value to a ChoiceField (**init** of Form class)

```
self.fields['thread_type'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, 
    widget=forms.Select, 
    initial=thread_type)
```

The form which is created with `thread_type` with the above code doesn't pass is_valid() because 'this field(thread_type) is required'.

-EDIT-
found the fix but it still perplexes me quite a bit.

I had a code in my template

```
   {% if request.user.is_administrator() %}
      <div class="select-post-type-div">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        {{form.thread_type}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      </div> 
   {% endif %}
```

and when this form gets submitted, request.POST doesn't have 'thread_type' when user is not admin.

the view function creates the form with the following code:

```
form = forms.MyForm(request.POST, otherVar=otherVar)
```

I don't understand why giving initial value via the the following(the same as above) is not enough.

```
self.fields['thread_type'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, 
        widget=forms.Select, 
        initial=thread_type)
```

And, including the `thread_type` variable in `request.POST` allows the form to pass the is_valid() check.

The form class code looks like the following

```
class EditQuestionForm(PostAsSomeoneForm, PostPrivatelyForm):
    title = TitleField()
    tags = TagNamesField()


    #some more fields.. but removed for brevity, thread_type isn't defined here 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """populate EditQuestionForm with initial data"""
        self.question = kwargs.pop('question')
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')#preserve for superclass                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        thread_type = kwargs.pop('thread_type', self.question.thread.thread_type)
        revision = kwargs.pop('revision')
        super(EditQuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #it is important to add this field dynamically     

        self.fields['thread_type'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, widget=forms.Select, initial=thread_type)
```

Comment: Can you show more code? when do you run this line?

Comment: Thanks. updated the question with relavant code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding this field dynamically, define it in the class appropriately:

```
class EditQuestionForm(PostAsSomeoneForm, PostPrivatelyForm):
    title = TitleField()
    tags = TagNamesField()
    thread_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, widget=forms.Select)
```

When creating the form instance set an intitial value if needed:

```
form = EditQuestionForm(initial={'tread_type': thread_type})
```

And if you dont need this field, just delete it:

```
class EditQuestionForm(PostAsSomeoneForm, PostPrivatelyForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditQuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if some_condition:
            del self.fields['thread_type']
```

When saving form, check:

```
thread_type = self.cleaned_data['thread_type'] if 'thread_type' in self.cleaned_data  else None
```

This approach always works well for me.

Comment: certainly can adapt your way of doing it. I prefer setting initials inside the Form class if possible though. Because what to use as initial value can take quite a bit of code sometimes and I dont want it in my views...

Comment: you can still set an initial value inside the Class, just for some reason i thought you need to set it dynamically each time

Comment: I can set the initial value inside the class, but .is_valid() will raise error, if the field is required and given initial value, but not given a value

Comment: it happens also after you delete it?

Comment: It happens, when I create the form that way in GET request, and present the form, and then user submit the form with POST. the field with initial is not set when POST.